# How to delete \n \t from txt file without using regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, text-files

**Input**: The input is read from a text file: `while ($data = FGets($soubor)) { ... }`.

**Output**: I would like to safe content to DB (import) without `\n \t`.

I think, that it offers an alternative for trim:

```
while () ...
$editedText = trim($data, "\t");
```

I need \t, \n and check in **whole** txt document. Any suggestions and samples?

**What is the best way for this easy task without RE**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) function is your new best friend.

---

```
$editedText = str_replace(array("\t", "\n"), "", $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

- `strtr`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php

  strtr($s, array("\r"=>" ", "\n"=>" ", "\t"=>" "));
- `str_replace`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

  see other answer

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
 s.trim();
```

it helps to lose whiteSpace, \n, \t and so on from both ends of the string.